# Is it possible to create calendar meeting via AWS SDK API for WorkMail?

Tags: java, rest, calendar, aws-sdk

Is it possible to create calendar meeting via AWS SDK API for WorkMail?
The goal is to create meeting in a calendar (it is supported by AWS WorkMail Calendar manually)

I was looking for Java/rest API and cannot find any endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

The AWS SDK for WorkMail only provides administrative API's which will not allow you to achieve your goal of creating a calendar item.

You can create calendar items via EWS using this library: https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api

You can find the EWS end-point for your region here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/workmail.html

-R